# How do I make a component reload after I did a submit on server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, angular

I'm working on a simple project using nodejs and angular 2.
In my client project I have a component which has a form and a submit event. When I throw this event all data from the form is properly sent to my node application.
But I have another component which has a table where I list all registers located on my database.

Everything works fine. But I should make my table load in the same time after I've sent my submit.
I have no idea how I can do this.

I tried implement something like this:

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees: string[];

  constructor(private employeeService : EmployeeService) {
    this.employeeService.employeeRequest().subscribe(employees => {
      this.employees = employees;
    })
   }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

And in my register component I did this method:

```
onRegister(){
    const Employee = {
      name : this.name,
      familyName: this.familyName,
      participation: this.participation
    }
    if (!this.validateService.validateRegister(Employee)){
      this.alertMsg = JSON.stringify({'msg': 'All fields must be filled'});
      console.log(this.alertMsg);
      return false;
    } else {
      this.registerService.employeeRegister(Employee).subscribe(data => {
        this.alertMsg = JSON.stringify({'msg': 'Employee registered successfully'});
        console.log(this.alertMsg);
        return this.router.navigate(['/list']);
      });
    };
  };
```

My tests show that my code works fine, but my table just load properly at first submit. After that I have to refresh manually the browser to load my table again.
Is there someone who know what I'm doing wrong or can tell me some way to code that?

Comment: Instead of doing a page refresh, you could call recall your `employeeRequest()` to repopulate `this.employees = employees;`

Comment: Hi @LLai thank you for you answer. But just another question. If you see my code again I call employeeRequest() inside of constructor. I know a little bit about client side and know that each component have your life cicle along the constructor life. So how do you suggest about where I can recall my employeeRequest?

Comment: You could move the call into it's own method. Then call it from the constructor and from the success callback of your `employeeRegister().subscribe`. As a sidenote, I would move your api call to the ngOnit method instead of the constructor. It is typically safer to keep the constructor lean and move your logic into ngOnInit. This is because angular controls when it calls ngOnit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. After I got the suggestions I tried another strategies. First I've simplify my two components as a single component. Then I moved my logic from the constructor to a method called dashCall() which I call inside my constructor and in the final of onRegister() method.

The final code looks like this:

```
export class EmployeeRegisterComponent {

public name: string;
  public familyName: string;
  public participation: number;
  public alertMsg: any;
  public employees: string[];

constructor(private validateService : ValidateService,
              private registerService : EmployeeService,
              private employeeService : EmployeeService) {
                this.dashCall();
              }

  onRegister(){
    const Employee = {
      name : this.name,
      familyName: this.familyName,
      participation: this.participation
    }
    if (!this.validateService.validateRegister(Employee)){
      this.alertMsg = JSON.stringify({'msg': 'All fields must be filled'});
      return false;
    } else {
      this.registerService.employeeRegister(Employee).subscribe(data => {
        this.alertMsg = JSON.stringify({'msg': 'Employee registered successfully'});
        this.dashCall();
    });
    };
  };

  dashCall(){
    this.employeeService.employeeRequest().subscribe(employees => {
      this.employees = employees;
    });

  }
}
```

I know it's not the best way to implement this. But in the end I got what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your constructor to a function, and than you call it on ngOninit, so every time your list component initialize your list of employees will load again, something like this:

```
export class EmployeeListComponent implements OnInit {

  public employees: string[];

  constructor(private employeeService : EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadAllEmployees();
  }

  loadAllEmployees() {
    this.employeeService.employeeRequest().subscribe(data => {
      this.employees = data;
    });
  }
}
```

Also see Angular life cycle hooks documentation to understand more about ngOnInit and others:

https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: The ngOnit lifecycle will not be called again unless the component is destroyed and re-initialized. `loadAllEmployees()` will need to be called after a user is successfully registered.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but the code doesn't work properly. I'm get the list automatically at first time that I submit my form, but if I try by a second time my list don't load. And I have to refresh the browser manually to see the results. Another suggestions?